# Is there a way to gracefully refuse to install an opam package on an unsupported OS?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am developing an opam package which, while in the future hopefully will work on all OSes, currently only builds on Linux. I want to tell a user who tries to install on e.g., MacOS, that the process will not succeed. I've seen things like this in the opam package description:

```
opam-version: "2.0"
authors: "Person Maintainerson"
maintainer: "Person Maintainerson"
build: [
  ["./configure"
  "amd64-linux" {os = "linux"}
  "amd64-macosx" {os = "macos"}
  "amd64-cygwin" {os = "cygwin"}]
  [make]
]
install: [
  [make "install"]
]
synopsis: "A one-line description"
url {
  src: "proto://path/to/source.tar.gz"
}
```

But I don't know how to tell opam to *not* do something.

In the [opam manual](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Manual.html#opam) there is a description about how to print specific messages for failures, but from the example it is not clear to me what the syntax is for `<filter>`.

> `post-messages: [ <string> { <filter> } ... ]`: allows one to print specific messages to the user after the end of installation. The special boolean variable failure is defined in the scope of the filter, and can be used to print messages in case there was an error (typically, a hint on how it can be resolved, or a link to an open issue). success is also defined as syntactic sugar for !failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `available:` field which should work for this: http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html#Advanced-usage

> OS constraints: The available field is a formula that determines your package's availability based on the operating system or other global opam variables. For example:
>
> `available: [ os != "macos" ]`

In your case I believe it should be `[ os = "linux" ]`.

Btw, if you decide to use the `dune-project` file to generate your `opam` file, you'll need a template, like this: https://github.com/yawaramin/ocaml-decimal/blob/2907175c02ca1bb117ee9703b8d642b721a3d6e8/decimal.opam.template

This is because `dune-project` files don't (yet) support the `available:` opam field, so they require this extra template file to pass it in.